# Merging [aircraft-identification] and [aircraft-recognition]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

There are currently two tags with the same meaning, with most questions belonging to the former: [aircraft-identification](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft-identification) and [aircraft-recognition](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft-recognition).  [One of the few questions](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12907/what-uk-aircraft-looks-like-an-islander-but-with-twin-fins) in the latter category is tagged with both.

Can these be merged into [aircraft-identification](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft-identification) and a synonym added from [aircraft-recognition](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aircraft-recognition)?

Comment: Makes sense to me. I suspect that 'recognition' was introduced by a non-native English speaker (some other languages use the same word for both purposes).

Comment: I've performed this merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no one has answered, I'll make my comment into an answer :-)

Yes, I think they should be merged as proposed. *Identification* is the appropriate word in English therefore it should be the main tag. *Recognition* is fine as a synonym; it may be the word that some non-native English speakers think of first.